# Google App Scripts & Google Sheets - When email added to cell, automatically add edit access for that email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

It this possible with Google App Scripts?

Using Google Forms the user will add their email in the text field, and click submit. The data is then sent to Google Sheets (working). Here is what the results look like.

| Timestamp | Email | Something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Example1@Example.com | ... |
| 01/02/2022 | Example2@Example.com | ... |

Once the emails are added to the Google Sheet, I would like Google App Scripts to get the values of column B (containing the emails), and add them as an editor.

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to set this trigger?
   *OnChange...when the form data is received, a timer, or something else.*
2. How do I get the script below to create the correctly formatted array so it does not throw the error.

**Expected Array Format**

```
const emails = [
    "billy.goat@gmail.com",
    "jenkins.waddlesworth@gmail.cm",
    "enola.lamb@gmail.cm",
    ];
```

**Current Formula With Error**

`Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.addEditor.`

```
function addEditAccess() {
 const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Emails");
 const emails = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
 SS.addEditor(emails);
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are asking but it sounds like you think that if a script modifies a google spreadsheet that it will trigger an onEdit trigger.  And I think the answer is no.  But you could just use the script that edits the  spreadsheet to send the email.

Comment: If I were you. I will write a function in the FormApp and use OnFormSubmit trigger. Get the email from nth answer and then call Drive API to insert permission.

Comment: @Cooper Basically I am wanting a user to submit a Google Form. Upon submission, their email is sent to a Google Sheet, and Google App Scripts then adds their email as an editor so they can edit the Google Sheet. If I cant automatically run the script when the Google From data is sent to the Google Sheet, perhaps I can just run the script every 30 min or something. I cant seem to get the array working though. I have updated my question.

Comment: If I understand you then it seems like using onFormSubmit trigger should work for you.  There have been a lot of question where people whish to send emails from form submissions.

Comment: @Cooper onFormSubmit seems like a great solution for a trigger. Thanks for that. As for the second part "send emails from form submissions" that is not what I am trying to achieve. I do not wish to send emails. I wish to get all the emails from column B, and give them edit access to the google sheet. I am just stuck with the getRange/getValues since its not forming the correct type of array for the script to run.

Comment: `let emails = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat(); ` assuming your data starts on row 2 and that you want a flattened array as opposed to a 2d array.  If you wish a comma separated list of emails it would be `emails.join(",");`

Answer (score 1):

On the google form, open up script editor, and add the following code. Then set the trigger to: Use onFormSubmit

```
function addEditAbility() {
 const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Emails");
 const emails = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
 SS.addEditors(emails);
}
```

@Cooper @Liquidkat for the help with the trigger solution.